# Is it possible to retrieve the contents of a Google Sites page via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sites

I have been looking for Javascript code to access the Google Sites API, but I can't find anything definite.

All I want to do is be able to take the contents of a page I made on Google Sites and display them on another website I own.

Is this possible, and if so, are there tutorials or example code available?

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve contents of Google Sites via API:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ContentFeedGET

You could create a PHP/Python script on your own server to execute the API commands on demand and return the result. Via JavaScript/AJAX you could access it local on your server, without cross origin problems.